# Parsing octal string to integer javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I parse a string containing an octal number like `"0o123"`?

When I try `parseInt("0o123")` it just gives me 0

Comment: Use `Number` instead of `parseInt`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[The "0"-prefixed octal literals and octal escape seq. became deprecated.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal)

You can write a [valid octal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal#valid_octal_numbers) number as follows;

- Use a leading zero followed by the letter `o` or `O`

  `cons n = 0o123`

  ```js
  const test = 0o123;
  console.log(test);
  // 83
  ```
- For **octal escape sequences**, you can use hexadecimal escape sequences instead:

  `const n = '\xA9';`